# How to setup SSL/OPENSSL on Oracle APEX running on Windows server and Jetty web server

Tags: windows, oracle, ssl, apex

Oracle APEX 23.2
Windows 2022
Standalone ORDS
Jetty web server

I have tried setting up CERTBOT for windows and tried setting up the path to the certificates. I also tried to force the 8443 port on ORDS to enable https but unfortunately it didn't work.

I want to enable HTTPS and SSL on my Oracle APEX server.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  This question does not fit the programming focused nature of Stackoverflow. I would recommend you use one of the better sites on the stackexchange network for this kind of question. Ask your question on https://serverfault.com or https://superuser.com